# Processor Speedup Calculation Difference

Tags: cpu-architecture, parallelism-amdahl

I am trying to understand why Amdahl's law does not apply to this situation?

Let's say we have two configs

Config 1 has L1 access latency (hitDelay and missDelay as 1 cycle) Config 2 has L1 access latency as 7 cycles.

Assuming load and store are 30% of the processor time, we expect a speed up of 1/(0.7 + 0.3/7) = 1.35

However, when I run the two configurations on an actual simulator that simulates a ROB based processor and calculate speedups using cycles, the speed up is 1.12.

Why is the speed up different from what was calculated using Amdahl's law. I am thinking Amdahl's law does not apply because of some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amdahl's "law" assumes times for separate parts don't overlap.

The whole point of a ROB for out-of-order exec is to find instruction-level parallelism and hide latency.  That's why performance of a whole sequence of instructions is *not* the sum of any single "cost" number for each instruction separately, except on the simplest CPUs.

e.g. [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca) (modern x86 makes it even more complex by each instruction possibly having different *front-end* cost in uops, but even with a simpler RISC machine, you still have back-end port pressure vs. possible latency bottlenecks).